# App rejected on playstore due policy violation default phone handler

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-play-console, policy

I am trying to upload an bundle to play with the following permissions:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

My app's core functionality is to work as a complete dialer like other phone apps like google phone, it shows call history, contacts place calls, etc. I have filled the declaration form and also gave reasons why I need the following permissions but still, my app is getting rejected again and again, also filed an appeal for the same still waiting for a response, please can anyone guide  me what I am doing wrong.

below is the message sent by Google:-

> Issue: Violation of Permissions policy    After reviewing your app, we
> found that it doesn’t qualify to use the requested permissions for the
> following reason(s): Requested permissions do not match the core
> functionality of the app You declared the Default Phone handler (and
> any other core functionality usage while the default handler) as the
> core functionality of your app. However, after review, we found that
> your app does not match the declared use case(s). Learn more about
> permitted uses and exceptions. Please either:
>
> • Make changes to your app so that it meets the requirements of the
> declared core functionality or,
>
> • Select a use case that matches your app’s functionality

Comment: have you found the solution yet? I am also having the same problem, if you have solved it can you give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Some of [requirements](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/default-handlers#follow-requirements-default-handlers) may not be met:

- Your app must be able to perform the functionality for which it's a default handler. For example, a default SMS handler should be able to send text messages.
- Your app must provide a privacy policy.
- Your app must make its core functionality clear in the Play Store description. For example, a default Phone handler should describe its phone-related capabilities in the description.
- Your app must declare permissions that are appropriate for its use case. For more details about which permissions you can declare as a given handler, see the guidance on using SMS or call log permission groups in the Play Console Help Center.
- Your app must ask to become a default handler before it requests the permissions associated with being that handler. For example, an app must request to become the default SMS handler before it requests the READ_SMS permission.

Comment: I have crosschecked the above and all the conditions are met still my app has been rejected please can you suggest something else